Find the expansion of $(1/N)\sum_{k=1}^N(x_{N,k}-x_{N-1,k})$ where $x_{N,k}=(-1)^{\lfloor N/(2k-1)\rfloor}N\pmod{(2k-1)}$
Looking for a solution and asymptotic expansion of the sum as $N \rightarrow \infty$
$$\frac{1}{N} 
\sum_{k = 1}^{N} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{N/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor} N \left({\textrm{mod}\ \left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\right) \\
- \left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{\left({N - 1}\right)/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor} \left({N - 1}\right) \left({\textrm{mod}\ \left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Numerically the asymptotic limit is $0.30685622$.
I can define the average over the modular terms as
$$\left<{N \left({\textrm{mod}\ \left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\right)}\right> = 
\frac{1}{2} \left({2\, k - 2 - 0 + 1}\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left({2\, k - 1}\right)$$
A bound estimate of just the sign terms is
$$\frac{1}{N}\, |\sum_{k = 1}^{N} 
\left({- 1}\right)^{\ell}| \le 
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} |\left({- 1}\right)^{\ell}| =1$$
where $\ell = \lfloor{N/(2k-1)}\rfloor$ or $\ell = \lfloor{(N-1)/(2k-1)}\rfloor$
The full expression (sum) is
$$
- \frac{1}{2\, N} 
\sum_{k = 1}^{N} 
\left[{\left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{N/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor} - \left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{\left({N - 1}\right)/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor}}\right] \left({2\, k - 3}\right) 
+
\frac{1}{N} 
\sum_{k = 1}^{N} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{N/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor} N \left({\textrm{mod}\ \left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\right) \\
- \left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{\left({N - 1}\right)/\left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\rfloor} \left({N - 1}\right) \left({\textrm{mod}\ \left({2\, k - 1}\right)}\right)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where the first sum averages to something like $1/N$ or more likely $1/\sqrt{N}$.
The sum over the alternating sign terms is related to the random walk in 1 dimension where
$$
{S}_{1\, D} \left({a, n}\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{a \left({n}\right)} \left({- 1}\right)^{\lfloor{\alpha\, n}\rfloor}$$
where in the case $1/\alpha = 2k-1$ and $a(n)$ is the upper limit which again in this case becomes $N$.  See Eric W. Weisstein, "Random Walk-1-Dimensional".

Is the sum in the question body supposed to be a matrix sum?

No matrix, just a sum with floor functions and modular arithmetic

Then what are the stacked lines inside {bmatrix}?

Oh, that is just the formatting used in Latex to make the expressions look nice.  I am copying a lot of material straight out of my research paper, so some editing or more removal of the extra formatting should be done so as not to confuse reviewers,  This helps fit the expression on one or two lines.

Are you sure that sum goes until $k=N$ ? Should n't it be 2k-1 = N ?
